# ¿Por qué necesito un doble apuntador para eliminar el primer elemento de una linked list?

Tags: c, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Necesito saber por qué necesito un doble apuntador para poder eliminar el primer elemento de una linked list en el lenguaje de programación C...

```
void remove_first_item(node_t **head) {
    node_t *new_node = 0;

    printf("%d\n", (*head)->next);
    new_node = (*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    *head = new_node;
}
```

... y por qué este otro código (con un solo apuntador) no funciona (?)

```
void remove_first_item(node_t *head) {
    node_t *new_node = 0;

    printf("%d\n", head->next);
    new_node = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = new_node;
}
```

Paso los argumentos para cada una de las funciones respectivamente de la siguiente manera:

```
remove_first_item(&head);

remove_first_item(head);
```

Siendo `head` un apuntador de tipo `node_t`, y este tipo se crea a partir de una estructura:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

node_t *head = NULL;
head = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

Los programas los ejecuto habiendo dos elementos dentro de la linked list, el primer código funciona bien, el segundo no, y necesito (como ya dije antes) saber por qué no, siendo que la dirección de `(*head)` y `head` es la misma en ambos casos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un puntero no es más que una variable cuya particularidad es que almacena direcciones de memoria. Así, en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int array[100];
int *ptr = array;
```

Al copiar el puntero no estás creando una copia de las 100 posiciones de `array`, sino que coges la dirección de memoria donde empieza esa variable y eso es lo que almacena `ptr`.

Pues bien, ¿qué sucede si posteriormente trabajamos con `ptr`?

```
ptr[0] = 10;
std::cout << array[0];
```

Acabamos de modificar la primera posición de `array`. Algo lógico y normal por otra parte. Sin embargo, ¿qué sucede si modificamos la dirección de memoria de `ptr`?

```
int array2[5];
ptr = array2;
ptr[0] = 11;
std::cout << array[0];
```

Ahora `array` no se ha visto modificado. Algo que, por otro lado, es totalmente lógico ya que antes hemos echo que `ptr` apunte a `array2` en vez de a `array`.

Es decir, los cambios que se hagan en la región de memoria apuntada por el puntero serán cambios visibles desde otras variables, mientras que hacer que el puntero apunte a otra región de memoria será un cambio exclusivamente local, solo afecta al puntero.

Pues bien, en la función que indicas:

```
void remove_first_item(node_t **head) {
    node_t *new_node = 0;

    printf("%d\n", (*head)->next);
    new_node = (*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    *head = new_node;
}
```

Es facil verificar que usando punteros simples el programa va a dar problemas:

```
void remove_first_item(node_t *head) {
    node_t *new_node = 0;

    printf("%d\n", head->next);
    new_node = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = new_node; // <<--- Problema
}
```

Fíjate en la línea destacada, en esa línea estamos modificando la dirección de memoria almacenada en `head`. Ese cambio, como hemos comentado hace un momento, es un cambio local, es decir, únicamente ésta variable `head` será la que se vea afectada por el cambio... el resto de variables no se van a ver afectadas. Luego al abandonar el programa la función el cambio hecho en esta última instrucción se pierde y el puntero `head` que tu has creado fuera de esta función:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

node_t *head = NULL;
head = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t)); // <<--- ESTE
```

va a seguir apuntando al elemento que acabas de borrar.

Comment: Vaya! Cuando dijiste que solo estaba modificando la variable head dentro de la función y no fuera, esa fue la clave! Ahora entiendo.

Puedo eliminar el último nodo a través de *head porque no estoy modificando *head en sí, sino solamente uno de los elementos a los que hace referencia. Y eliminar el primero necesito modificar *head y por eso es que necesito el puntero a puntero (doble puntero) Es así verdad? Confirmame y marco tu respuesta como la correcta! Gracias en adelanto.

Comment: @codenoschool es como dices. Me alegro de que te haya quedado claro el concepto. :)